# using sstream in mingw 2.95 compiler

Tags: c++, header, mingw, sstream

Is it possible to use sstream header in mingw 2.95 compiler?.If, it is, then how? I am using C-Free 4.0 and it comes with default mingw2.95 and cygwin compiler

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to include it?

Comment: ya, I get an error, it says its not found in the directory

Comment: what compilation command are you using? Maybe your IDE has a way of showing it.

Comment: [Version 2.95](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-2.95/) isn't exactly the latest release. Using most any other release would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

g++ 2.95 is really from the stone age. There was no `<sstream>` at that time.
(A lot of other things are missing too or don't work like they do in more recent compilers.)
It comes only with the obsolete `<strstream>` which is based on `char*`.

Your options are:

- Get a newer compiler. Almost anything newer will do.
- If you are really forced to use this one for some reason, you can copy `sstream` from gcc 3.x. That worked for me at that time. But be prepared for more surprises.
- Stick with `strstream` but that's ugly...

Answer (score 0):

sstream is header file that is part of c++ standard library. It is not optional or specific to the gcc compiler. You should be able to include it simply like this:

```
#include <sstream>
```

Make sure you are compiling with g++ and not gcc.

Comment: And you must compile the source as c++ code. If you compile it as C code, including `sstream` wont work. (use a .cpp or similar file extention will probably work)

Comment: I am compiling it through an IDE, I am not aware on the command it uses in this case

Comment: @MiNdFrEaK What IDE? Look around in the settings and find the compiler your are invoking.